# Remove all special characters from a phone number string entry except + occurring only at first place

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

I want to remove all special characters from a phone number string entry except + symbol. That too, if it is occurring only at first place.
Example : +911234567890 should be valid but +91+1234#1234 should be invalid.

Comment: you haven't tried anything

Comment: Plz can u provide ur code.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
String number = "+91+1234#1234"
number=number.replaceAll("[\\D]", "")
```

This will replace all non digit characters with space but then for your additional "+" in the beginning ,you may need to add it as a prefix to the result.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to use regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String sPhoneNumber = "+911234567890";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[+]\\d*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Phone Number must start from  + ");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: yeah I tried this matcher and I am able to detect that the string has symbols but I am not able to replace them.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input=scan.next();
        String onlyDigits = input.replaceAll("[^0-9]+","");
        System.out.println(onlyDigits);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String arg[]){

String num="+45*#545454*j";
String edited="";

for (int i=0;i<num.length();i++){

char c=num.charAt(i);
    if (i==0&&c=='+'){
        edited+=c;
    }
    else if (Character.isDigit(c)){
        edited+=c;
    }

}
System.out.println(edited);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for you.But please give a try and then ask the question so that you can improve yourself. At least give a try to understand the code without directly use it

```
public static boolean isValid(String number) {

        if(number.startsWith("+")){
            number=number.substring(1);
        }
        try {
             Integer.parseInt(number);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: hey, I agree I havent posted the code but it doesnt mean I havent tried anything. also, I asked for replacing the characters, NOT for finding it by catching exceptions. thnx anyways for your suggestion:)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [MaskFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) to constrain the input, something like this

```
    MaskFormatter formatter = null;
    try {
        formatter = new MaskFormatter("+###");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
```

The string "+###" in the constructor defines what can be typed in the textfield; in this case the first character needs to be '+' and the following three needs to be digits. See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html) for details.